# Add an Entity object with its Related Entity based on primary keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an entity like this:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FullText { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

This entity has relations to `Category`:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Post> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when inserting data into the `Post` table, I use this code:

```
var post = new Post
{
    Category = _categoryService.FindById(model.CategoryId),
    FullText = model.FullText,
    Tags = model.Tags,
    Title = model.Title,
};
_articsleService.Save(post);
```

This code works fine, but it has 1 fetching data form database. In entity objects that has more than 3 relations, I think this way not so good. Therefore, another way can be like this:

```
var post = new Post
{
    Category = new Category { Id = model.CategoryId },
    FullText = model.FullText,
    Tags = model.Tags,
    Title = model.Title,
};
_articsleService.Save(post);
```

But, when the code is run, I get this exception:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Is there any best solution for this problem?

Comment: When using " Category = new Category" you are creating a completely new entity, even if you set its ID to an existing ID in the DB, the ORM still manages it as a new Entity to store in the DB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your post model the FK to CategoryId

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FullText { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Then just add a new post after updating your db model.

```
var post = new Post
{
    CategoryId = model.CategoryId,
    FullText = model.FullText,
    Tags = model.Tags,
    Title = model.Title,
};
_articsleService.Save(post);
```

That's it, EF will do the rest for you.

Your current approach leads to creating a new Category which does not work bc the same primary key already exists and inserting into an identity column is not enabled by default. This is how change-tracking from EF works. EF creates a proxy from each database row as an entity in your code and tracks this entity during application lifetime.

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking).